# Why does Microsoft's own USB-CDC driver refuse to register GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT interface?

Tags: windows, device-driver

By saying Microsoft's USB-CDC device driver, I mean usbser.inf and usbser.sys .

[image: usbser.sys driver on Windows 10]

However, these CDC "virtual COM Port device" do not register for **GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT device-interface-class**. That is, by using

```
SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE|DIGCF_PRESENT);
```

we cannot find the CDC COM port by enumeration.

Only when we enumerate by **GUID_DEVCLASS_PORTS device-setup-class** can we find those CDC COM ports, that is,

```
SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVCLASS_PORTS, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT);
```

This apparently violates what Microsoft says in MSDN [Configuration of COM Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/519CA9C8-BC67-4A85-87AE-6015C6212DEA), where it tells us in point (1) that a COM port device must register for **GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT**.

> Starting with Windows 2000, a COM port is a type of serial port that
>   complies with the following additional requirements:
>
> - (1) You access the COM port through an instance of the COM port device interface class. The GUID for this class is
>     GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT, which is defined in Ntddser.h.
> - (2) You operate the COM port by using the 16550 UART-compatible interface that is defined in Ntddser.h.
> - (3) To ensure compatibility with most applications that access COM ports, you should assign a symbolic link name that uses the standard
>     naming convention "COM", where  is the COM port number (for
>     example, COM1). If you use a COM name, you must obtain the COM port
>     number  from the COM port database. COM port numbers should only be
>     used with COM names.

There is a famous web page http://www.naughter.com/enumser.html that shows multiple ways to enumerate COM ports.

- Its UsingSetupAPI1() is the GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT enumeration method.
- Its UsingSetupAPI2() is the GUID_DEVCLASS_PORTS enumeration method.

Then why does Microsoft insists to violate what he says himself, up until Windows 10. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: I enumerate `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT` and I don't believe I've ever had this problem.  Is the call failing, returning no result, or returning results other than the USB CDC you want?  What descriptors does the USB device report (in particular, does it report as a modem or composite device)?

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstand the context. Please double check it is a USB-CDC device driven by Microsoft usbser.sys, and you understand your code correctly. If it is really a USB-CDC device, Windows 10 has stock driver for it(usbser.inf, usbser.sys), but no stock usbser.inf for Windows 7/8.1.

Comment: Well, I wrote a com port enumeration library, and I was using an FTDI converter, which doesn't use usbser.sys, and then my coworker used it with a USB CDC device that used usbser.sys, and at first he had problems, but then he found out something was missing on the device side (either some CDC message types were not being handled, or the CDC subclass was wrong, or something like that) and after fixing it things started working smoothly.  So be careful of functions that the CDC specification says are optional -- they may not actually be optional when being controlled by usbser.sys

Comment: Do distinguish between the words "class" and "interface".  Usbser.sys is a class driver, it provides services for multiple serial ports.  It is up to the device manufacturer to make the interfaces available.  Keep reading on that same page: "the combined operation of the class installer for the Ports device setup class and the Serial function driver configure a device as a COM port".  Two drivers.  If he did not do that correctly (do they ever) then calling SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo() next is another way to obtain info about each port.

Comment: Maybe you are right as for the "class driver" statement. But, could you show me a real world driver example(cite a manufacturer's device model) that works with usbser.sys and have GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT correctly registered? We all know that learning Windows driver development is impossible without real working examples.